# Laravel Nova n+1 problem when running sql inside fields()

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

For some reason, I need dynamically add columns in the fields method. This is not only dynamic columns but also contains computed fields.

This is very simplified version of what I'm trying to do inside fields():

```
$additional_fields = [];

Product::visible()->each(function($attr) use (&$additional_fields, $request) {
    $additional_fields[] = Text::make($attr->name, function() use ($attr, $request) {
        $first_subscription = $this->subscriptions()->whereHas('product', function($q) {
            return $q->where('visible', 1);
        });

        ...
    }
}
```

This, of course, causing the N+1 problem as statements for Product and Subscription are executed on every row.

I need to move this piece of code somewhere else and run it only once. I can't figure out how to do this yet.

Comment: you can use the `with()` method as a regular eloquent query. Also note that Nova resources have a `$with` property to load relations

Comment: I know that, but this will not help because the fields() are executed every row.

Comment: So get the entries in the nova resource’s constructor and save it in a property. Then in the `fileds` method use the property

Comment: This is really bad. Nova calls fields() a bunch of times to load tables etc. You really don't want to add queries to it.

Answer (score 0):

Your can use `indexQuery` method in your resource to load relationships

```
/**
 * @param NovaRequest $request
 * @param \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder $query
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
 */
public static function indexQuery(NovaRequest $request, $query)
{
    $query = $query->with('relation');

    return $query;
}
```